# make json with elasticsearch functions in java

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch

I have a problem with understanding how to make json object in java. 
I have to get certain data from elasticsearch through java and I also have a json that functions, but I have no idea how to make such json with functions available.

Is it possible to do this with the `SearchResponse` class and its functions?
Might `QueryBuilder` help?

This works with the Sense plugin in chrome:

```
GET _search 
{
 "query": {
     "constant_score": {
        "filter": {
            "and": {
               "filters": [
                  {"term": 
                    {"_type":"budget"}                      
                  },
                  {"term": 
                    {"_index":"dbs_project"}                      
                  },
                  {"term": 
                    {"month":"x"}                      
                  },
                  {"term": 
                    {"account_id":"y"}                      
                  }
               ]
            }
        }            
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`QueryBuilder` should definitely work for you. To build a query like you require using the API, you will need to do something like this:

```
QueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.constantScoreQuery(FilterBuilders.andFilter(FilterBuilders.termFilter("_type", "budget"),
                FilterBuilders.termFilter("_index", "dbs_project"), FilterBuilders.termFilter("month", "x"),
                FilterBuilders.termFilter("account_id", "y")));
```

And you will use `SearchResponse` to execute the query and fetch results like this:

```
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch(index).setTypes(type)
                .setQuery(query).execute()
                .actionGet();
```

where `client` is the instance of your `TransportClient` and `index` and `type` correspond to the elasticsearch index and type you want to query from.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried   `XContentBuilder`.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/1.6/generate.html